# Send JSON Array and store in database using api calls

Tags: swift, swifty-json

I want to send a json object through Post method  in this following format

```
[
    {
        "product_id": 8,
        "quantity": 2
    },
    {
        "product_id": 19,
        "quantity": 1,
        "variations": {
            "pa_size": "XL"
        }
    }
]
```

and store this JSON in sql database
in following format 
[image: POST MAN SNAP]

here is my code:

```
//i get the products id and quantity

 for var i=0; i<ct ; i++ {
   let   paramsArray = [["product_id":  (prId[i]), "quantity" :   (productQty["\(prId[i])"]!)]]

//converting array to json using SwiftyJSON

 let paramsJSON = JSON(paramsArray)
 let paramsString = paramsJSON.rawString(NSUTF8StringEncoding, options: [])

 //appending products to array

   cartProducts.append(paramsString!)
       }
   //printing array products
      print("cartPro:\(cartProducts)")
```

printed output of array comes like this i also tried to remove backslash

```
cartPro:["[{\"product_id\":19,\"quantity\":1}]", "[{\"product_id\":8,\"quantity\":1}]"]
```

i want out put like this so i can send through post method using api:

```
[{"product_id":19,"quantity":1}, {"product_id":8,"quantity":1}]
```

is there any other way i can append JSON objects to array and send? or i'm doing it wrong?

please help me

Comment: You should search before posting questions. They are called escape characters -  Special Characters like Quotes, slashes and others require ` \\` to make that character to remove its special functionality. Took this answer from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10117031/escape-quotes-in-objective-c?answertab=oldest#tab-top).

Comment: Your array is not what you think it is. It only holds *one* value, a string, and because this string has quotes in it, they have been escaped. You need to look into how you're constructing the array: you can't build an array inside a for loop this way, it will only hold last item.

Comment: Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26857881/is-there-any-way-to-fix-a-json-response/26860779#26860779

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your cartProducts is of of type AnyObject.

declare cartProducts as any object

```
var cartProducts = [String]()
```

change it to

```
var  cartProducts =[AnyObject]()
```

and try appending and it should work.

after appending the out put you will get something like this in your console log

```
cartPro:[{"product_id":19,"quantity":1}, {"product_id":8,"quantity":1}]
```

than you can send that variable through your api.